# XPages - Auto launch not working on DMZ server

Tags: http-status-code-404, xpages, dmz

I have an application with the web browser launch properties set to open designated XPage (home.xsp).

It works fine on our test server but not on the new DMZ server where I get a 404 error (HTTP Web Server: Item Not Found Exception)

I've looked on Stack Overflow but haven't found anything to point me in the right direction. Would someone let me know how I can resolve this?

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: I should add that if I point to the application with the full URL eg. (https://www.example.com/myapp.nsf/home.xsp), I am able to launch the XPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would try some things

1. clean the project
2. manually build the project
3. check the data\Technical support folder and the data\Domino\workspace\logs folder on the server for clues

Comment: Thank you Frederik. I was able to find the point of failure in the workspace logs.

Comment: Dan, to aid what Fredrik suggests, make sure you use Log File Reader 2.0 available from openNTF.  It is nearly as essential as the debug toobar.